# SELECT * vs SELECT * LIMIT (Performance)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, sql-limit

I have more than 10K records in a table `t1` having a column `uid`.
 **I have 5 records with `uid='xyz'`** 
Now which approach out of 2 is better

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE uid='xyz';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE uid='xyz' LIMIT 5;
```

**There are only 5 records with uid as xyz **

Comment: avoid `*` if you are concerned about performance

Comment: what do you observe when you run each query ??

Comment: That depends.  Are you going to use all of the records, or just the first five?

Comment: what do you want first 5 or all? your two statements return totally different results. how can a comparison be possible?

Comment: @bansi Results would be same friend, cuz i have just 5 rows with `uid` as `xyz`

Comment: in theory the one with `limit` could be faster, unless the 5th row where `uid=xyz` is the last row in the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does limiting a query to one record improve performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488/does-limiting-a-query-to-one-record-improve-performance)

Comment: If you want performance, put an index on uid. It won't mather how many items you have in your table.

Comment: What happens when you actually try the two queries against your actual data and **time** the performance? IOW, **actually perform a benchmark test**?

Answer (score 4):

In general, you use `limit` with an `order by` clause.  Otherwise, the results are arbitrary and may not be repeatable.

If you want exactly *5* records, then use `limit 5`.  If you want all the records, then do not use the limit.  The performance of the two should be very, very, very similar if both are returning the same data.

Comment: I am considering a possible situation where the 5 results are placed on the top. Will the first query search the entire table and the second will stop searching as soon as the LIMIT clause is fulfilled ?

Comment: It will stop as soon as it finds the required amount of rows.

Comment: @GauravSharma What does "on the top" mean when you don't `ORDER BY` anything?

Comment: @Carsten I mean if the first 5 rows I inserted had userid='xyz', the rest of the rows had some different userid. If mysql traverse through all queries like a linear search, it would stop as soon as it finds a total of 5 matches, since I specified `LIMIT 5` (I am not sure if it happens this way)

Comment: @GauravSharma . . . Depending on how your interface is set up, the rows may be being returned as they are found anyway.  So, although you might be waiting for the scan to complete, you might be getting the data anyway.  However, without an `order by`, you cannot depend on the order of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Asumming, as you explained it, there is (absolutely certainly) 5 rows such as `uid='xyz'`:

- both statements will perform almost exactly the same, *if there is an index on `uid`* since MySQL will easily "see" that there is only 5 rows to inspect.
- If you don't have an index on `uid` the `LIMIT` version will behave better, since it will tell MySQL to stop searching after the 5<sup>th</sup> matching row -- avoiding to "spend time" examining the remaining rows.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason not to use limit is that there are only 5 records now. There might be 17 a year from now.