# How's the performance in php with a request sql with LIMIT in terms of RAM and time of execution

Tags: php, performance, optimization, ram

I'm writing a **PHP** script but I'm facing a little question,
What the concrete difference between :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

and :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

In terms of **RAM** and **time of execution** used in the server ?

Edit: Actually I was opting for the first sql request, but for a precise need, I have to recheck a certain amount of data with my **PHP** script to build another amount of data (smaller) but I cannot do this with sql pure. (I use `fetch_array` in all the result until I have the amount I want) So I want to know (before I do anything wrong), what solution is faster for the client (sql + php) and what solution is the more safier in terms of load into the server ?

Edit2 :Re-paste the ORDER BY clause

Comment: a limited resultset executed faster and consumes less ram, it seems like a common sense

Comment: @RoyalBg in general yes, though it makes sense to take a closer look.

Comment: ... unless you have one thousand rows and you limit to two thousand. But that's common sense as well.

Comment: Yeah I know but in pure sql it's faster to do a sql request without Limit, so between the loss of ram and time to construct the resultset, and the time gained by not adding the limit to the sql request...

Comment: Setting limit should be faster in pure SQL as well, unless there's other factors that you're introducing such as ORDER BY clauses

Comment: @fandegw I doubt that it's faster, if you open a mysql console and say `SELECT * FROM table` where you do expect more than 1 row, and next time you say `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1`. However, afterwards, when you fetch the elements, in like an array, you should be pretty sure that PHP will iterate faster through array with X elements than with X+N elements

Comment: Ok, actually I'm introducing an ORDER BY clause, sorry for not posting the complete sql request :/

Comment: Actually, there are incomplete answers presented here, due to unclear goal. The second query is *faster* for **mysql** to perform. The first query will return **less** results, making it faster for **php** (since it just has to populate an array with a smaller dataset). What is your actual question then? We have two players here (php and mysql) which have to perform certain work. The query with no limit can in theory produce a huge result set that might exhaust memory at PHP side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, isn't the answer obvious?

If you limit the result set of a select query, then the amount of data inside that result set is reduced. The result of this, when looking at phps memory usage depends mostly on one central thing:

1. if you retrieve *all* of the result set in a single go, for example by using something like `fetchAll()`, then the whole result set is read into memory.
2. if you process the result set in a sequential order, then only one element of a result set is read into memory at a given time. Thus, unless you copy that, the memory footprint is limited.

Another thing is performance inside php: obviously the more elements in the result set you process, the more load you generate. So limiting the size of the result set will probably reduce load, *unless* you have a good way to pick only a certain range of elements to process from the result set.

As a general rule of thumb: *always* only retrieve the data you really require and want to process.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's does not change anything in me most common cases.

Excellent response on which cases are improved : [Does limiting a query to one record improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488/does-limiting-a-query-to-one-record-improve-performance)

And for your case, this article is about offest/limit performances : http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/