# No performance gain using LIMIT on SQLite query?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, limit, prefix

I have a SQLite database with 460.000 words ordered alphabetically, and I want to check if there is a word starting with some specific letter or prefix.

```
SELECT word FROM en WHERE word like 't%' LIMIT 1
```

I expected this query to return the first word that starts with t. The problem is that on Android OS, this query is slow. If I change it to:

```
SELECT word FROM en WHERE word like 'trick%' LIMIT 1
```

It runs very fast. The difference is that there are 27.300 words that starts with "t" and only 60 words that starts with "trick".

I was hoping that LIMIT 1 would stop the search and return the first hit. But apparently that is not how it works. The database is properly indexed:

```
CREATE TABLE "en" (
     "word" text(12,0) NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
    PRIMARY KEY("word")
);
```

I'm stuck at this problem. Any advice?

The code execute the query is written in Unity:

```
public bool CheckIfWordListContainsAWordThatStartsWith (string word)
{
    string query = "SELECT word FROM en WHERE word LIKE '" + word + "%' LIMIT 1";
    SQLiteQuery qr = new SQLiteQuery(db, query);

    if (qr.Step())
    {
        // string result = qr.GetString("word"); // No need to take care of the actual result
        qr.Release();         
        return true;
    }
    qr.Release();         
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it was long ago but i remember that there was a big difference in performance in like vs glob operators, i can't tell you which was faster though..

Comment: @pskink GLOB is normally faster because it is case sensitive and thus can use indexes without COLLATE NOCASE.

Comment: These queries should have exactly the same speed. Ensure to run them multiple times (so that the data is cached in both cases), and check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) if the index is being used (you have to run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN on the device).

Comment: sorry, EDIT: limit will effect only when there is NO unique-index, so in your case, no use of limit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488/does-limiting-a-query-to-one-record-improve-performance

Comment: try to unset `word` as PK, or try glob as advised

Comment: @CL now it explains why i noticed a big difference,  thanks

Comment: I tried GLOB and it is slower. I tried removing the PK and both LIKE and GLOB are slow. When I use the built-in SQLite on Mac OS X, both my queries above with LIKE and PK are blazingly fast. But on Android, the first query is really slow. Indexing did not help, the primary key already does that job.

Comment: and what about EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN?

Comment: @Yazan That has no effect on *this* query because LIKE is not an equality comparison.

Comment: @Funkystein `word` is already indexed.

Comment: EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN: SEARCH TABLE en USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_en_1 (word>? AND word<?) (~30000 rows)

Comment: On Mac OS X, using LIMIT 1 speeds up the query notably. On Android there is no difference if I use LIMIT or not. I guess it first finds all the 27.300 rows that matches the query and after that limits to 1 hit.

Comment: @Funkystein PRIMARY KEY is implemented with an index.

Comment: Is that the EQP output of the Android device? Because it looks perfectly fine. And how exactly are you running the query?

Comment: @CL, yes it is the output from Android. I'm programming in c# in Unity and I access the Android's native SQLite.

Comment: @CL. could this be a sqlite version issue? just a thought...if Per Ekstig can try on serveral devices, we may get a better idea, FOR Per Ekstig:: if you got dead end on this, consider changing the approach, split the data into 3 or 4 table, where table1 has data for letters starts with A to E, table2 F to J ... etc, and you can check the word (in java) to find out which table to look into and build the sql statement based on that...

Comment: Thanks CL, yes, I considered creating a set of tables, e.g. with word prefix from length 1 to 5. So checking the word "TRICKY" would first take the prefix "TRICK" and check in the table with 5 letter words. But finally I decided to skip sqlite and save my wordlist as a byte array and implement my own binary-search function.