# MySQL limit syntax with Query performance

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I want to know how it is affected in query performance to use limit syntax
There are 180000 rows. So I would select data using limit syntax.
So I want to know the relationship between limit syntax and query performance.

Comment: If there weren't some recent improvements I do not know of, there is no relationship between these two.

Comment: LIMIT can slow down the query execution.. When you use big offsets like LIMIT 10000000, 10000000 .. because 20000000 records needs to be fetched.  And most likly MySQL needs to use a temporary table to execute the query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you do not use LIMIT, you will receive all data, which has to be send over the communication channel for you to throw it away, which will be even slower. It is only slower compared to having a position-column, which can be used by the query, but this is not possible/practicable in all cases.

Comment: This may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500/2225030

Comment: _"I want to know how it is affected in query perfomance"_ So why are you not writing queries and measuring their performance for yourself?

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes no sense. It is `ORDER BY` that is usually costly on large data. However, 180000 rows is a rather big amount to select and sort anyway. Who wants to scroll through 180000 rows? Usually one is interested in particular data. Once data is restricted to a reasonable amount (with `WHERE` usually), there is less data to sort and the process less costly hence.

Comment: Thanks guys. best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` usually saves part of the cost of sending large result sets from the MySQL server to the requesting client. It's  good to use `LIMIT` if you need only a few result set rows, rather than simply skipping un-needed rows on the client side.

There's a notorious **performance antipattern** using `LIMIT`.  A query like this

```
 SELECT a,whole,mess,of,columns,...
   FROM big_table JOIN big_tableb ON something JOIN big_tablec ON something ....
  ORDER BY whole, mess DESC
  LIMIT 5
```

in MySQL wastes server resources (time and RAM). Why? It generates a big result set, then sorts it, then discards all but a few rows.

Another **performance antipattern** is `LIMIT small_number, big_number` applied to a complex result set. It has to romp through many rows to get a small number of rows.

You can work around these with a deferred join pattern, something like this:

```
   SELECT a,whole,mess,of,columns,..
     FROM (
         SELECT big_table_id
          FROM big_table JOIN big_tableb ON something JOIN big_tablec ON something ....
         ORDER BY whole, mess DESC
         LIMIT 5, 200000
        ) ids,
   JOIN big_table ON ids.big_table_id = big_table.big_table_id
   JOIN big_tableb ON something JOIN big_tablec ON  something ...
```

This pattern orders and then discard just some `id` values rather than a whole mess of columns.

Using `LIMIT` really **helps** performance in situations where the result set is  ordered via an index.  For example, if you have an index on `datestamp` and you do

```
 SELECT datestamp, col, col
   FROM table
  ORDER BY datestamp DESC
  LIMIT 20
```

the MySQL query planner can scan backwards through the `datestamp` index and retrieve just twenty rows.

Comment: (It's `LIMIT offset, limit`, so some of your comments are backwards.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to quickly gauge the impact of any SQL commands is using `EXPLAIN` and checking the number of rows etc.. Starting with `EXPLAIN`ing the query is usually a good route. Just put 'EXPLAIN ' before your query to find out how expensive it is.

**Sending large data sets might not be the problem -- it 's the sorting**

In my experience it's the usage of `ORDER BY` which is *extremely* slow. Frequently `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` are used together for obvious reasons, and it's the sorting that's the slow part, rather than `LIMIT` itself.

`LIMIT` does avoid returning large data sets which might otherwise be discarded, but usually in practice the database is on the same local network or even the same server. Network performance & large datasets usually aren't the limiting factor. Instead, it's the cost of sorting the data before returning it which is highest. You can get the most benefit by optimising for those sorts, eg by creating indexes matching your queries.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` usually ignores `LIMIT`.  So, don't depend on it to help here.